# Program won't continue when I press enter

Tags: c++

I have never run into this issue before. When I press enter accept the userInput the program does not execute. Any reason why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
  char data;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
};


struct node* newNode(int idata){
  struct node* node = new struct node;

  node -> data = idata;
  node -> left = NULL;
  node -> right = NULL;

  return node;
};

void getUserInfo(string &userInput, int &lengthString){
  cout << "A string that contains a dot(.) will be invalid!" << endl;
  cout << "Enter a string ->";
  cin >> userInput;

  // getting the length of string
  lengthString = userInput.length();
}

void stringToChar(char *& charArray, int &lengthString){
  for(int i = 0; i < lengthString; i++){
    cin >> *(charArray+i);
  }
}

int main(){
  string userInput;
  int lengthString = 0;

  char * charArray;
  charArray = new char [lengthString];

  getUserInfo(userInput, lengthString);

  stringToChar(charArray, lengthString);

  /*struct node *root= newNode(9);
  root ->left = newNode(20);
  (*root).right = newNode(3);
  cout << root->right->data;
  */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's see: your `main()` allocates an array containing zero characters. Then you proceed to write however many characters gets read from `std::cin` into the array, that can only contain a maximum of zero characters. Yes, I'd say that the chances of your program successfully running, from that point on, are not very good.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: P.S. What exactly do you expect to accomplish by: 1) Reading some string from standard input, 2) Obtaining the size of the string, 3) Executing a second loop to read from `std::cin`, one character at a time, the exact same number of characters that's contained in the first string. This makes no logical sense. What you need to do is not waste a single additional moment, before [scheduling an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), in order to straighten everything out.

Comment: In `stringToChar` you do more `cin >>`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Use `std::string` and stop torturing yourself with char arrays.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I keep seeing you in the c++ comments and every time you say use rubber duck debugging.

Comment: Not every time, but very often, true. I'm a big, big fan of my rubber duck. It helped me many, many times in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue was that you had another `cin` in your `stringToChar` method. Assuming that you wanted to make the string into a char array, (Judging by your parameters and what you declared that is what you wanted) I changed the method to accomplish that.

```
void stringToChar(char *& charArray, int &lengthString, string &userInput){
  for(int i = 0; i < lengthString; i++){
    charArray[i]=userInput[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugger step by step execution. When I ran your code it works if you enter something for userinput. However if you just press enter without any text, looks like it's not your program not continue working, but command prompt is not returning anything to your program. Enter gives new line character, which is ignored by cin, as far as I know. Try pressing enter few times and it will just display new line in comand prompt, while your program is still executing on same line.

If you want to use pause, better use `os.system('pause')` for Windows. Unix should have something similar.

Did I answer your question?

P.S. Since you are using dynamic memory, looks like you know already, that you'll need to free it later.

Comment: I don't think that was what he was asking. He wanted to prevent the weird pause; he did not want to find a way to replicate it.